# How can I set property of an object to a function in a class?

Tags: javascript, class, object, scope, this

I'm learning JavaScript (means the code presented here has some experimental features just because I want to learn them) and I ran into a problem.
My concept is when the layout changes it calls the render function and according to the layout the render function creates the new class which handles the dom. The method I want to execute is set in the constructor of the Appl class. When I want to execute this method I get an error message

```
Uncaught TypeError: Object must be an instance of class Appl
```

which points to `appl.#config.callback` method. If I'm not mistaken my problem is that not the method of the instance is passed as a function but the method of the class, and the method is not static so it cannot handle.
How can I set the `appl.#config.callback` function to point to the `appl.render` method without writing name of the instance (which doesn't work either because I want to set it in the constructor before the instance is passed to the appl var)?

```
  $(document).ready(function(){
    appl = new Appl(config, "appl");
    appl.render();
  });
```

The Appl class itself:

```
class Appl{
    #config;
    #layout;

    constructor(config,selfName){
      this.#config = Object.create(config);
      this.#config.setCallback = this.render;
      this.#config.setObjectName = selfName;
    }
    get getConfig(){
      return this.#config;
    }
    get getLayout(){
      return this.#layout;
    }

    #selectLayout(){
      switch (this.#config.layout) {
        case "login":{
          this.#layout = new Login(this);
          break;
        }
        case "workspace":{
          this.#layout = new Workspace(this);
          break;
        }
        default:{
          return false;
        }
      }
    }

    render(){
      this.#selectLayout();
      this.#layout.render();
    }
  }
```

And the config object:

```
  let logoutTime = 500;
  let config = {
    layout: "login",
    container: ".container",
    logoutTime: ()=>{
      return logoutTime * 1000;
    },
    set setLayout(value){
      this.layout = value;
      this.callback();
    },
    set setCallback(value){
      this.callback = value;
    },
    set setObjectName(value){
      this.selfName = value;
    }
  }
```

And the appl instance of Appl class after it is created:

```
#config: Object
callback: ƒ render()
  length: 0
  name: "render"
  arguments: (...)
  caller: (...)
  [[FunctionLocation]]: (index):140
  [[Prototype]]: ƒ ()
  [[Scopes]]: Scopes[2]
   0: Script
    Appl: class Appl
    Login: class Login
    Workspace: class Workspace
    appl: Appl {#selectLayout: ƒ, #config: {…}, #layout: Login}
    config: {layout: 'login', container: '.container', logoutTime: ƒ}
    loginPanel: // the DOM
    logoutTime: 500
    selfName: "appl"
  [[Prototype]]: Object
#layout: Login
#selectLayout: ƒ #selectLayout()
getConfig: (...)
getLayout: (...)
```

Thanks in advance.

EDIT: functional fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/gazsop/9yLoprj1/2/

Comment: "A JavaScript identifier must start with a letter, underscore (_), or dollar sign ($). Subsequent characters can also be digits (0–9)." You have some with `#` which might also be confused with a hashbang comment see: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Grammar_and_types

Comment: Because they are private. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Classes/Private_class_fields

Comment: I made a snippet of your code fragments.  It would help make your question more easily reproduced and easier to answer if you made if functional please.  Note how as it stands you DO have variables that start with "#" in the names (note: site does not do an automatic format well with the # names in the class, apology for what in the snippet creation when formatted

Comment: I edited the post, link at the end.